# Docker Restart Configuration

Tags: bash, docker

I am not able to find any documentation on this. I launch a container that mount some NFS volumes and executes some entry point scripts. The script receives parameters from the docker run command.

Here is an example command I use:

```
docker -H 192.168.0.31:4000 run -v /nfs/bench:/nfs/bench:shared 
-e BENCH_SHARED_FOLDER=/nfs/bench -e BENCHID=354re34343  
--restart always -d meandocker/benchnew:v1
```

So, this command has such things as the port, the volume to mount and other environment variables. My question is, what happens to all theses pieces of information when the container restarts? Is the exact same command used by docker to start the new container?

Comment: This doesn't answer your question, but I would recommend using docker-compose to make setups like this easy to restart. 
https://docs.docker.com/compose/

Answer (score 1):

Yes.

As long as the container is **not** removed, any configuration that you specified for your `docker run` command when creating the container will be persisted within Docker. So if the container restarts, it will keep the same configuration.

However, I would recommend using the docker-compose tool for declaring your containers and managing their configuration.